# Interrupt and reset UIScrollView animation from UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview

I am making a Karaoke app that a user needs to be able to start-over by pressing a button.

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains a large block of text in a `UITextView`.

I am using `UIView.animateWithDuration` to scroll the text for a certain duration. I need to be able to interrupt/stop the animation and reset it back to the beginning.

Unfortunately, for me, whenever I stop the animation, the `UITextView` disappears and I can't seem to re-add it.

```
let bottomOffset:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.textView.frame.size.height)
UIView.animateWithDuration(NSTimeInterval(duration),
    delay: NSTimeInterval(0.0) ,
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear,
    animations: {
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)
    },
    completion: { finished in
        reset()
    }
)
```

I am stopping the animation by calling:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.0, animations: {
    self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0), animated: true)
})
```

I need to figure out how to:

- **Stop** the animation
- Keep the `UITextView` visible
- Scroll the `UIScrollView` back to the top
- **Start** scrolling again

My codebase is in **Swift**, but I will gladly accept answers in **Objective-C**.

Comment: I won't be able to try out any answers until after work hours PDT.
I apologize in advance if my replies are too slow.

Comment: Why don't you just set up a timer that calls the scroll method every second with an animation? When you hit stop the timer stops, when you hit start it starts again, and when you want to reset it you just need to have it scroll to the top.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but wouldn't that cause it to scroll jerkily?

Comment: it shouldn't because you can still have it be animated to view points. You will have to play with it for sure.

Comment: I was able to sidestep the issue by using:

    
`    self.scrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()`
    

to stop the animations. Then I just manually re-initialize and reset everything to their initial states. 
This doesn't answer the original question, but it does solve my problem.